# How to execute multiple commands simultaneously using os.system() in python

Tags: python, unix, operating-system, command

```
import os  
import sys

command_0 = './main'
command_1 = './main'

os.system(command_0)
os.system(command_1)
```

I want to run a script called 'main' twice simultaneously using python, the problem is that command_0 run for 5 seconds and only when it finishes the command_1 is called. Is it possible to run both simultaneously ?

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options:

1. add & to the command so it will run in the background

`os.system(command &)`

2. use queue / subprocess:

   ```
   def worker():
       while True:
           item = q.get()
           os.system(item)

   q = Queue()
   for i in tasks:
        t = Thread(target=worker)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

   for item in tasks:
       q.put(item)

   q.join()
   ```